# border radius with css triangles

Tags: cross-browser, css, css-shapes

I have [a rectangle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9xDVj/3/) where each side of the diagonal has it's own color

[image]

```
div {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;    
    border-left: 150px solid green;
    border-top: 100px solid gray;
}
```

Now I wanted to add a border-radius to the div, but then I noticed that this works fine for all sides except for bottom left.

So if I add:

```
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 0;
```

I get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9xDVj/4/):

[image]

.. but as soon as I add a bottom left border-radius, I get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9xDVj/6/):

[image]

1) Why does this happen?

2) Is there an easy fix?

Edit:

I'm using Chrome, but I just looked a firefox and IE and the results are different!

Firefox:

[image]

IE 11

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: Have you tried to place this whole triangle inside a parent div, which has the `border radius + overflow hidden`? Something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/uvVgJ/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add a wrapping container:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

with this style:

```
.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

`overflow: hidden;` should do the trick.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/9xDVj/8/

Comment: Of course, but it doesn't answer the first question.

Comment: @HashemQolami I believe it happens because the behavior in such situations is not defined in spec (at least I'm not aware of it), so it's up to browser vendors specific implementation.

Comment: @dfsq - The different results that each browser produces does seem to support your claim that the result here isn't defined in the spec

Comment: @dfsq Agreed. Seems only Firefox is rendering the box properly as there's no right and bottom border to be rounded.

Comment: Reading a [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/#the-border-radius) it makes me feel that it's actually natural that there are not radius when the border width value itself bigger then radius.